# Pass multiline argument with xargs

Tags: xargs

I want to pass file content as quoted programm argument with `xargs` to skip temporary file creation.

With temp file I can do like this:

```
myprogram > /tmp/lld.json
zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "`cat /tmp/lld.json`"
rm /tmp/lld.json
```

But I don't want this extra actions with `/tmp/lld.json`.

So I try to use `xargs` like this:

```
myprogram |
xargs -e -I'{}' zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "'{}'"
```

guiding with `xargs` manpage:

> -I replace-str
>
> -e[eof-str] ... If *eof-str* is omitted, there is no end of file string..
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

But `xargz` executes `zabbix-sender` many times with each of the lines.

I guess that `-I` and `-e` options are mutually exclusive options. But I also assume that I misinterpret the `xargs` manual..

Comment: Seems that `xargs` isn't the tool you'd need here (at least from your original description), in fact, no other tool than the shell itself, by passing `myprogram` output directly as `-o` argument, i.e.: `zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "$(myprogram)"` (here the `$(...)` construct is equivalent to backticks one)

Comment: Thx, @jjo! Your comment sounds frustrating, because..  `myprogram` is multiple lines inside bash-script..

Comment: I see the workaround solution in transforming bash-script code into functions, then I can use it like this: `myfunct() { ...; }; zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "$(myfunct)"`, it's not exactly what I want. But it works..

Comment: It seems that `xargs -e` allows to perform multiple lines into single line, this is evident from this simple experiment: `echo -en "1\n2" | xargs -e echo 34` output: `34 1 2`. One more workaroud - transform JSON document into single string

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "`myprogram`"
```

If you insist on using `xargs` to do exactly that, then use `-0`:

```
myprogram | xargs -0 -I{} zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -s testhost -k llditem -o "'{}'"
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly how it works now.
But the question is about `xargs`..